# How to implement Interface Comparable, Collection.sort() using SQL in java?

Tags: java, database, sorting, comparator, compareto

That is simple Library project. It has to load the data from the database, by asking the user to search based on **keywords** or **genres**.
I have two classes. One of them is the *Book class.* :

```
package library;

import java.sql.Date;

public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {

String title;
String author;
Date date;
String ISBN;
String format;
String publisher;
float price;
String[] keywords;
String[] inputArray;
String input;

public Book(String title_param, String author_param, java.util.Date date_param, String ISBN_param,
        String format_param, String publisher_param, float price_param, String keywords_param) {

    title = title_param;
    author = author_param;
    date = (Date) date_param;
    ISBN = ISBN_param;
    format = format_param;
    publisher = publisher_param;
    price = price_param;
    keywords = keywords_param.split(",");

}

public void setUserInput(String userIn) {
    input = userIn;
}

private int getRelevance(String userInput) {
    inputArray = userInput.split(",");
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != keywords.length; i++) {
        String in = inputArray[i];

        for (int l = 0; l != keywords.length; l++) {
            if (in.equals(keywords[l]))
                num++;
        }
    }

    return num;
}

public int compareTo(Book o) {
    if (this.getRelevance(input) > o.getRelevance(input)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.getRelevance(input) < o.getRelevance(input)) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
}
```

In the second one I want to CALL in the right way Collection.sort() and CompareTo(), in a way that it shows the books that contain at least one of these keywords. BUT it has to show the books on top that have the most keywords from the input.
The collection and the compare parts
are NOT not working right now.

```
    package library;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LibrarySearch {
    static ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    ArrayList<LibrarySearch> genres = new ArrayList<LibrarySearch>();
    static ArrayList<LibrarySearch> keywords = new ArrayList<LibrarySearch>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        load_data();
    }

    private static void load_data() {
        Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<Book>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Book first, Book second) {
                if (first.compareTo(second) == 1) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (first.compareTo(second) == -1) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return 0;

            }
        });

        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/library", "root", "123456");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Choose to search by keywords or genres");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();

            if (input.equals("keywords")) {
                System.out.println("Enter your keywords: ");
                String[] keyWordsInput = scanner.nextLine().split(",");
                ResultSet result = null;

                for (int i = 0; i != keyWordsInput.length; i++) {
                    result = statement
                            .executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM book WHERE keywords LIKE '%" + keyWordsInput[i] + "%'");
                }

                while (result.next()) {
                    int id = result.getInt("id");
                    String title = result.getString("title");
                    String author = result.getString("author");
                    Date date = result.getDate("date");
                    String ISBN = result.getString("ISBN");
                    String format = result.getString("format");
                    String publisher = result.getString("publisher");
                    float price = result.getFloat("price");
                    String keywords = result.getString("keywords");

                    System.out.println("ID = " + id);
                    System.out.println("TITLE = " + title);
                    System.out.println("AUTHOR = " + author);
                    System.out.println("DATE = " + date);
                    System.out.println("ISBN = " + ISBN);
                    System.out.println("FORMAT = " + format);
                    System.out.println("PUBLISHER = " + publisher);
                    System.out.println("PRICE = " + price);
                    System.out.println("KEYWORDS = " + keywords);
                    System.out.println("___________________________________________________________________________");

                    if (title.equals("I,Robot")) {
                        Book new_book = new Book(title, author, date, ISBN, format, publisher, price, keywords);
                        books.add(new_book);
                    }
                    if (title.equals("Catch-22")) {
                        Book new_book1 = new Book(title, author, date, ISBN, format, publisher, price, keywords);
                        books.add(new_book1);
                    }
                    if (title.equals("Pride and Prejudice")) {
                        Book new_book2 = new Book(title, author, date, ISBN, format, publisher, price, keywords);
                        books.add(new_book2);
                    }
                    if (title.equals("Gone with the Wind")) {
                        Book new_book3 = new Book(title, author, date, ISBN, format, publisher, price, keywords);
                        books.add(new_book3);
                    }

                }
                result.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();

            } else if (input.equals("genres")) {
                System.out.println("Enter your genres" + ": ");

                String genresInput = scanner.nextLine();
                ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(
                        " SELECT * FROM books_genres JOIN book ON (book.id = books_genres.book_id) JOIN genre ON (genre.id = books_genres.genre_id) WHERE name LIKE '%"
                                + genresInput + "%' ");
                while (result.next()) {
                    int id = result.getInt("id");
                    String name = result.getString("name");

                    int book_id = result.getInt("book_id");
                    int genre_id = result.getInt("genre_id");

                    int id1 = result.getInt("id");
                    String title = result.getString("title");
                    String author = result.getString("author");
                    Date date = result.getDate("date");
                    String ISBN = result.getString("ISBN");
                    String format = result.getString("format");
                    String publisher = result.getString("publisher");
                    float price = result.getFloat("price");
                    String keywords = result.getString("keywords");

                    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

                    System.out.println("Book ID = " + id1);
                    System.out.println("TITLE = " + title);
                    System.out.println("AUTHOR = " + author);
                    System.out.println("DATE = " + date);
                    System.out.println("ISBN = " + ISBN);
                    System.out.println("FORMAT = " + format);
                    System.out.println("PUBLISHER = " + publisher);
                    System.out.println("PRICE = " + price);
                    System.out.println("KEYWORDS = " + keywords);

                    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

                    System.out.println("Genre ID = " + id);
                    System.out.println("Genre Name = " + name);

                    System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");

                    System.out.println("Book ID = " + book_id);
                    System.out.println("Genre ID = " + genre_id);

                }

                result.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, wrong command");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("No successful connection");
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException x_not_found) {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By the looks of it, you know how to implement `Comparable<T>` since your `Book` implements it. What is your question? What is the problem? Please be more verbose, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: It is not working, I could not call it in the right way I guess. Thank you

Comment: "It is not working." -> What is "it"? As I said: please be more verbose. What parts are working? What parts are not working? From looking at your question, I am unable to deduce whether you have a conceptual problem, problems with the database connection, problems with sorting, some of them or all of them. A [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would also be appreciated.

Comment: CompareTo, Collection.sort().

Answer (score 0):

First off, since getRelevance() method returns int, I would suggest writing compareTo like this:

```
public int compareTo(Book o) {
    return this.getRelevance(input) - o.getRelevance(input);
}
```

Similarly, comparator would look like this:

```
Collections.sort(books, new Comparator<Book>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book first, Book second) {            
        return first.compareTo(second);
    }
});
```

As for calling, looks like you are sorting the empty list first, and then populate it with search results. I suggest moving the sorting part to the end of the load_data() method.

Answer (score 0):

One problem:  You're iterating over `inputArray` `keywords.length` times, which is probably not correct.  Don't know if that's your problem - it might be if the keywords array is much shorter than the input array.

The larger issue is iterating over keywords for ever element of inputArray.  Put your keywords in a HashSet and test for contains instead.